# Override specific method in imported class

Tags: python

I am building an application that can play several card games. At the lowest level, I have a Card class that will be imported by each game class, see below.

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank=None, suit=None):

        ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}
        suits = {'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Hearts'}
        assert(rank in ranks), 'Not a valid rank'
        assert(suit in suits), 'Not a valid suit'

        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    @staticmethod
    def rank_to_numeric(rank):
        if rank == 'J':
            return 11
        if rank == 'Q':
            return 12
        if rank == 'K':
            return 13
        if rank == 'A':
            return 14
        else:
            return int(rank)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'  # Example: 7 of Spades

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.rank_to_numeric(self.rank) < self.rank_to_numeric(other.rank)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.rank_to_numeric(self.rank) <= self.rank_to_numeric(other.rank)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.rank, self.suit) == (other.rank, other.suit)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not (self == other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.rank_to_numeric(self.rank) > self.rank_to_numeric(other.rank)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.rank_to_numeric(self.rank) >= self.rank_to_numeric(other.rank)
```

In most games, a 2 will be the lowest card and the Ace the highest. However, now I'm trying to implement a game class for the Dutch card game 'Toepen', in which the ranking is J-Q-K-A-7-8-9-10 (from low to high). Cards 2 to 6 are not used in this game.

I know I could add the ranking as a parameter to the construction of the Cards, though I wonder if it is possible to override the comparison methods inside the Toepen class after importing the Card class. See example below

```
import Card

class Toepen:
    """
    class for the popular dutch card game Toepen.
    Rules according wikipedia: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toepen
    The optional rules can be set in the settings
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # Set the round counter. A single game consists of 4 rounds
        self.round = 0

        # Set the trump (troef)
        self.trump = None

        # Set the highest card played so far
        self.incumbent = 0

        # Set the pile of cards so far played in this round
        self.pile = []

    # def Card.__lt__(self, other):
        # implement method here ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("foo")


class B:

    def new_foo(self):
        print("new_foo")

    def over_ride(self):
        A.foo = self.new_foo

    def __init__(self):
        self.over_ride()
```

This will reassign the `A` class's `foo`. If you will access `A` from anywhere in you code, it will have `new_foo`'s body from the moment you create `B`'s instance.

In your case, it will be something like

```
class Toepen:
    """
    class for the popular dutch card game Toepen.
    Rules according wikipedia: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toepen
    The optional rules can be set in the settings
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # Set the round counter. A single game consists of 4 rounds
        self.round = 0
        Card.__lt__ = self.new__lt__
    

        # Set the trump (troef)
        self.trump = None

        # Set the highest card played so far
        self.incumbent = 0

        # Set the pile of cards so far played in this round
        self.pile = []

    def new__lt__(self,other):
        pass
```